# Online VS type Editor

Tags: ide

A few months ago I stubbed across a really nice Visual Studio online Editor. That is not any of the following: [Amy Editor](http://www.amyeditor.com/), [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/), [Bespin](https://bespin.mozilla.com/), [Kodingen](http://kodingen.com/), [EditPad](http://www.editpad.org/), [TypeIt](http://www.typeit.org/), [PractiCode](http://www.landofcode.com/online-code-editor.php), [9ne](http://robrohan.com/projects/9ne/), [jsvi](http://gpl.internetconnection.net/vi/), [HTMLedit](http://htmledit.squarefree.com/).

Does anyone know of an online Editor that looks and feels like Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this one?: http://www.coderun.com/ide/

**Update:** As of 10/03/2012, this website is no longer online.

Comment: Thank you so much! Been looking for this for HOURS!